# Save lat and lng on leaflet map click event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new to leaflet and js and I am looking for a way to get the latitude and longitude from a leaflet map on a click event and pass it into an HTML text input.

I tried to use

```js
map.on('click', function(e) {
 var latitude = e.latlng.lat; 
 var longitude = e.latlng.lng;     
 var latt = document.getElementById("idfromHTML").innerHTML(latitude);
});
```

to save them on a variable, yet I cant seem to pass them in an HTML tag. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to put text into input, just add it to value
`document.getElementById("idfromHTML").value = latitude;`

Comment: Yours was a great help. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `<input>` you need to add a value:

```
document.getElementById("idfromHTML").value = latitude;
```

if you have a other html element you need to change the innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("idfromHTML").innerHTML = latitude;
```

Comment: InnerHTML should not be used due to the danger of XSS attacks